# AngularJS: Disable checkbox by pressing button ( function )

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to make a "clear" button, that clears everithyng, obviously, but I'm not able to disable the checkboxes.
I'm using AngularJS and JQuery and I'm working on a log in screen.

```
HTML:
<div id="page_signin_content" data-role="content" style="width:75%;margin:0 auto;"> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
<label for="basic">Usuario:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="username" id='username' />

<label for="basic">Contraseña:</label>
 <input type="password" ng-model="password" data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off"        id='pass'>
<br><br>

<div style="width:75%;margin:0 auto;">
    <div style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;">
      <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="remember_me" > Remember me

            </label>


    </div>

<fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
<div class="ui-block-a"><a ng-click='signIn(username,password)' data-role="button">Log in</a></div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><a ng-click='clear()' data-role="button" id="clear" >Clear</a>                                                                       </div>    
</fieldset>

</div>

</div><!-- /content -->
```

---

```
JS:
$scope.clear=function(){
                        $scope.username = "";
                        $scope.password = "";



                    }
```

Comment: What do you mean disable the checkboxes?

Answer (score 1):

at the first you should assign model to your checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="remember_me" ng-model="remember"> Remember me
```

and in clear function

```
 $scope.remember= false;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement is not much clear but you can disable the checkbox on click with the help of ng-disable and ng-checked. Thats why I have created demo for all the 4 cases

```
1.disable/enable toggle on click.
2.disable onclick. 
3.uncheck on click.
4.checked/unchecked toggle on click.
```

please see if this full fills your requirement. here is link
[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/5fwomqxd/)

here is my code

```
//html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h4>This toggles the disable enable</h4>
   <input    type="checkbox"   ng-disabled="checkMe"    />Toggles
    <button ng-click="check()">disable/enable</button>
       <br><br>
    <h4>This disables the checkbox onclick</h4>        
    <input    type="checkbox"   ng-disabled="checkMe1"    /> click to disble
    <button ng-click="check1()">disable</button><br><br>
    <h4>This unchekcs the checkbox</h4>          
    <input type="checkbox"   ng-checked="checkMe2"    /> click to disble
    <button ng-click="check2()">disable</button><br><br>
           <h4>This toggles check and uncheck the checkbox</h4>          
    <input type="checkbox"   ng-checked="checkMe3"    /> click to disble
    <button ng-click="check3()">disable</button>
</div>
    //app.js
    function MyCtrl($scope) {
       $scope.checkMe=false;
        $scope.check = function() {
        $scope.checkMe=!$scope.checkMe;
    }
        $scope.checkMe1=false;
        $scope.check1 = function() {
        $scope.checkMe1=true;
    }
        $scope.checkMe2=true;
        $scope.check2 = function() {
        $scope.checkMe2=false;
    }
        $scope.checkMe3=true;
        $scope.check3 = function() {
        $scope.checkMe3=!$scope.checkMe3;
    }
}
```